# Magento 2 : Create a button for change the customer email

Tags: magento2

I need to create a button in the info.phtml template on Magento 2, which allows to modify the user's email address. I need after clicking on the button that the table field becomes an input with a checkbox. If the checkbox is not checked the email address is modified only for this command, and if the checkbox is checked then the email address is modified for the user.

I found the layout and info.phtml, I already have the logic for the data recording but I don't know how to create the button, the input and the checkbox.

It should look like this screenshot

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgIEX.png)

Comment: You speak about magento 2 but your screen design comes from magento 1.

Comment: Yes I need to reproduce this feature of magento 1 on magento 2

Comment: There is build-in change customer email function for magneto 2 at account edit page

Comment: @L.C.EchoChan I know that, but I need to be able to edit the email from the order details page. I think with Knockout.js it's possible to transform the email field into an input and then make an AJAX call to a controller, but I don't know how to do that